# Invalid value given for parameter administratorLogin. Specify a valid parameter value

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-mysql-database

While create mysql server from azure portal, i am getting like this

```
{
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "InvalidParameterValue",
      "message": "Invalid value given for parameter administratorLogin. Specify a valid parameter value."
    }
  ]
}
```

Anyone please help me to fix this issue

i tried to create new mysql server in azure portal. I am getting error. i want to create mysql db in azure portal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i found the solution and resolved this issue. I am able create mysql db now. the problem is while mysql db i gave admin user name as admin/root. so i am getting above error. after read microsoft docs i found the solution for this issue.

[image]

[Official docs for create mysql server in azure portal link here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/mysql/flexible-server/quickstart-create-server-portal)

Comment: Also 'sa' won't work.